# Collapsing and Expanding Side Panels in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I apologize is this is a very simple task this is really my first time transitioning to react.

I have an existing application built with js/css/html that I am attempting to shift over to react. It has a full length horizontal side panel that is open by default, when the window is shrunk beyond a point it collapses with a hamburger icon, and expands again when the window is resized larger. Fairly easily done with media queries in css.

A perfect example is https://purecss.io/layouts/side-menu/ (note the side menu) This is exactly what the current app does.

I'm struggling to do this in react. I can build a side panel that is collapsible (https://reactjsexample.com/react-side-nav-component/) and mofify it for my needs, but I cannot figure out how to set it up so it collapses and expands by itself. I understand I can set it up react to use media queries, however I figured there was likely a more efficient way.

Any advice of good libraries to use, or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not media queries? the tool for that job i think.

Comment: Thanks for the advise Jure, I did just end up using media queries.

Comment: For anyone who encounters a similar issue, I used media queries and also property (isActive). When the media query fires or when a hamburger button is clicked it changes the isActive property to false which though css makes the side panel visible or not. The hamburger button sets it via on v-on:click method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
const Component = props => {
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateWindowDimensions)
    updateWindowDimensions()
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateWindowDimensions)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (windowWidth < 500) {
      closeModal()
      return
    }
    openModal()
  }, [windowWidth])

  updateWindowDimensions() {
    setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth)
  }
}
```